# Spam in Documentation discussion?

Tags: discussion, documentation, spam, documentation-discussion

I've noticed some spam (ad) in **Documentation -> Android -> Getting started with Android -> Discussion** ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/85/getting-started-with-android/discussion?page=1&pagesize=30&tab=active&type=all#)) from user [williamhawk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7854428/williamhawk):

[image: ad]

But there is no button to somehow flag the discussion to report it. Maybe we should have one?

Comment: My question is why a user with 1 rep can comment on that page at all if we aren't going to have a way to easily police it...

Comment: I've cleared the comment and dealt with the spam account, thanks for the heads-up! Yes, it is not helpful that flagging is not available there yet, or that new users can post like this. I'm sure the team will note this and take action.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes we have noted that. The work is being done in development and we ought to have it tested soon. Targeted for next week, but it's a lot of code.

Comment: *"... it's a lot of code"*... sounds more like 6-8 weeks then...